# combining three arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have three arrays of arrays. I essentially need them laid on top of each other.

```
first = [[111, 1], [222, 2], [333, 3]]
second = [[111, 4], [222, 5], [333, 6]]
third = [[111,7], [222, 8], [333, 9]]
```

Ideally it would be great if the final array looked like this:

```
final = [[111, 1, 4, 7], [222, 2, 5, 8], [333, 3, 6, 9]]
```

I looked at the product method in hopes that that could help but no go. I have also tried to loop over all three but I guess I'm not that smart.

Comment: Tried final = [one,two,three]?

Comment: Ruby on Rails is a web framework written in the ruby language. You'd look for how to mix these arrays in ruby. It looks like hashes could be a better choice than arrays.

Comment: I say Rails only because there may be some sort of rails ways of accomplishing this, and since there is no such thing as php on Rails and only Ruby on Rails I figured there should be know confusion. A hash would be a good way of doing it I suppose. I think I'm still at a loss of how to iterate the three and combine them the way I described. Thanks for you input.

Comment: Aren't you msising a closing bracket after `[[111,7]` in `third`? Should be: `third = [[111,7], [222, 8], [333, 9]]`.

Comment: There is no such thing as php in Ruby on Rails, but there is a thing called Ruby in Ruby on Rails. That's what you're asking about here.

Comment: As a side note, it's sometimes useful to know that the code is executed in a Rails app since Rails extends ruby core librairies (Array, Hash ...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Combine](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-2B) them, then [group](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) them, then [map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map) them to fit your specs:

```
(first + second + third).group_by(&:first).map { |k, v| [k, *v.map(&:last)] }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[first,second,third].transpose.map do |array|
  array.reduce { |init,e| init << e.last }
end

=> [[111, 1, 4, 7], [222, 2, 5, 8], [333, 3, 6, 9]]
```

To deal with several last elements in array:

```
[first,second,third].transpose.map do |array|
  array.reduce { |init,e| init + e.drop(1) }
end
```

Comment: This just got the last element of each array. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: The result is identical to your final array

Comment: So its supposed to work with more than 2 elems? You didnt told that in your question

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is working but I done it at the phone so... And for sure there are better ways to achieve it

```
first = [[111, 1], [222, 2], [333, 3]]
second = [[111, 4], [222, 5], [333, 6]]
third = [[111,7], [222, 8], [333, 9]]

all = [first, second, third]

hash = {}

all.each do |arr|
  arr.each do |elem|
    hash[elem[0]] ||= []
    hash[elem[0]] << elem[1]
  end
end

Array.new hash.map { |k,v| [k, *v]}
```

For more elems

```
hash[elem[0]].concat elem[1..-1]
```

Comment: You can also do `arr.each do |k, *v|` . The hash can also be stomped into an array with `hash.map(&:flatten)`